# How does source code manage white space and concatenation

Tags: php, whitespace, double-quotes, linefeed

In the following code:

```
    $email_body = 
       "message from $name \n" 
       "email address $visitor_email \n"
       "\n $message";
```

the fourth line generates a parsing error dues to an unexpected `"`, but the quotes seem to be correctly paired.  So why is (the final?) one in the last line "unexpected"?

I expected the result for $email_body to be:

```
    message from $name
    email address $visitor_email 

    $message
```

I've looked throught the syntax page on php.net/manual, and read the questions here on single and double quotes.  I can't find any exceptions for a line feed at the beginning of a string but that seems to be what it is.  Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't break the string up like that unless you use `.` to concatenate them back together!

So, either:

```
 $email_body = 
   "message from $name \n 
   email address $visitor_email \n
   \n $message"; // also the whole string on one line is fine
```

or

```
$email_body = 
   "message from $name \n" 
   . "email address $visitor_email \n"
   . "\n $message";
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run it, the error is on the third line, not the fourth.

The problem here is that you have a string literal next to another string literal with no operator between them.

This is wrong:

```
"foo" "foo"
```

as is:

```
"foo"
"foo"
```

You could do something like this:

```
"foo" . "foo"
```

or

```
"foo" . 
"foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is

> Error on line 5: parse error, unexpected
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING("email address $visitor_email \n"

This is where your error starts

```
$email_body = 
       "message from $name \n" // This line you need to add concatination
       "email address $visitor_email \n"
```

Then your code will look like

```
 <?php

 $email_body = 
       "message from $name \n". 
       "email address $visitor_email \n".
       "\n $message";
```